# Is there a DLL in Windows to implement Kerberos?

Tags: windows, authentication, client, kerberos, legacy

I need to implement Kerberos authentication as a replacement for LDAP, in fat client applications developed in various (legacy) languages. porting the application to .Net or Java (to use Jaas) is not an option.

I am looking for a DLL that would enable me to implement calls on my clients apps to AD as the Kerberos server.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos on Windows is available through [SSPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/security-support-provider-interface-sspi-), the Windows equivalent of GSS-API.

(You can also install MIT Kerberos or Heimdal; both are primarily Unix GSS-API implementations but have Windows ports available.)